# SQL Server query to get consecutive occurence start and end

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns (Machine, Time, Status) which stores information about different systems and its status captured at different time.

```
Machine Time                 status
-----------------------------------
MAC_1   2016-10-06 06:48    OFF
MAC_1   2016-10-06 07:48    OFF
MAC_1   2016-10-06 08:48    ON
MAC_1   2016-10-06 09:48    ON
MAC_1   2016-10-06 10:48    ON
MAC_1   2016-10-06 11:48    OFF
MAC_1   2016-10-06 12:48    OFF
MAC_2   2016-10-06 06:48    OFF
MAC_2   2016-10-06 07:48    OFF
MAC_2   2016-10-06 08:48    OFF
MAC_2   2016-10-06 09:48    ON
MAC_2   2016-10-06 10:48    ON
MAC_2   2016-10-06 11:48    OFF
```

Now I am trying to get the "consecutive" OFF and ON time window for each machines.

The result set we are trying to achieve is as below,

```
Machine   Status   StartTime               EndTime 
-----------------------------------------------------------
MAC_1     OFF      2016-10-06 06:48        2016-10-06 07:48
MAC_1     ON       2016-10-06 08:48        2016-10-06 10:48
MAC_1     OFF      2016-10-06 11:48        2016-10-06 12:48
MAC_2     OFF      2016-10-06 06:48        2016-10-06 08:48
MAC_2     ON       2016-10-06 09:48        2016-10-06 10:48
MAC_2     OFF      2016-10-06 11:48        2016-10-06 11:48
```

Please help.

Regards,
RON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic data island problem. If you have SQL Server 2012 or higher then you can use the Windowing functions to get the desired result as per following example:

```
DECLARE @MachineStatus TABLE
(
     [Machine]      NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[Time]     DATETIME
    ,[status]   NVARCHAR(5)
    ,PRIMARY KEY([Machine], [Time])
)


INSERT INTO @MachineStatus
(
     [Machine]  
    ,[Time]     
    ,[status]   
)
VALUES
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 06:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 07:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 08:48',    'ON'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 09:48',    'ON'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 10:48',    'ON'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 11:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_1',  '2016-10-06 12:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 06:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 07:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 08:48',    'OFF'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 09:48',    'ON'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 10:48',    'ON'),
('MAC_2',  '2016-10-06 11:48',    'OFF');


WITH CTE_MachineStateChange
AS
(
    SELECT   [Machine]  
            ,[Time]     
            ,[status]
            ,(
                CASE
                    WHEN LAG([status], 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY [Machine] ORDER BY [Time]) <> [status] THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
             ) AS [StateChanged]
    FROM    @MachineStatus  M
), CTE_MachineStateGroupByID
AS
(
    SELECT   [Machine]
            ,[Time]
            ,[status]
            ,SUM([StateChanged]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Machine] ORDER BY [Time] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [GroupByID]
    FROM    CTE_MachineStateChange
)
SELECT  [Machine]
        ,[status] AS [Status]
        ,MIN([Time]) AS [StartTime]
        ,MAX([Time]) AS [EndTime]
FROM    CTE_MachineStateGroupByID
GROUP BY [Machine], [GroupByID], [status]
```

Comment: Thank you Edmond. This solution worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have sql server 2008.

```
create table #test(mac varchar(100), mac_dt datetime, mac_stat varchar(100))

insert into #test values
('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 06:48', 'OFF') 
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 07:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 08:48', 'ON')
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 09:48', 'ON')
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 10:48', 'ON')
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 11:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_1', '2016-10-06 12:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 06:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 07:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 08:48', 'OFF')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 09:48', 'ON')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 10:48', 'ON')
,('MAC_2', '2016-10-06 11:48', 'OFF');

with cte as
(select mac, mac_dt, mac_stat, row_number() over(order by mac, mac_dt) - row_number() over(order by mac, mac_stat) as grp
 from #test)
select t1.mac Machine, t3.mac_stat [Status], t3.StartTime, t3.EndTime
from #test t1 cross apply(select t2.mac, min(mac_dt) as StartTime, max(mac_dt) as EndTime, t2.mac_stat
                            from cte t2 
                            where t1.mac = t2.mac and t1.mac_stat = t2.mac_stat
                            group by t2.mac, t2.grp, t2.mac_stat) t3
where t1.mac = t3.mac and t1.mac_stat = t3.mac_stat
and t1.mac_dt = t3.StartTime                                            
order by t1.mac, t3.StartTime
```

Comment: Thank you Shishir. This solution also gave me the expected results. I have a 2012 instance with me. So will be going with the first solution. Your solution helped me to understand how to do it if we had earlier versions.